# Leaving Israel to US

Tags: visas, usa, esta, israel, belgium

I'm a dual national Belgian/Israeli and I'm entering the US with my Belgium passport and ESTA visa, do I need a visa for Israelis to leave Israel, or is showing my Israeli passport enough?

Comment: You will just have to show his ETSA / EU passport at the Checkin counter if you will be asked ( probably ). as for immigration - you must do it with the Israeli passport by law .

Answer (score 4):

As an Israeli citizen, you don't need a visa to leave Israel. As long as you don't have a "stay of exit" order<sup>1</sup> (צו עיכוב יציאה מהארץ) against you, you are free to leave the country.

The only thing is that upon entering or leaving Israel you are required to present your **Israeli** passport and not a foreign one.

<sup>1 - A.K.A. Departure Prohibition Order</sup>